# getAddUrl($product) not working on CMS Blocks? (Magento CE)

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a template file in which I built an 'add-to-cart' button. The button uses the common link to add a product to the cart:

```
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)
```

I call my phtml file from a **CMS page** (via widget) and when I click on the button, the product is added correctly. The output of the command in the frontend is

```
https://www.myDomain.de/checkout/cart/add/uenc/[long alphanumeric string],/product/178/form_key/[alphanumeric string]/
```

and everything works fine.

Now, if I call the same phtml file from a **CMS block** I am not able to add the same product in the cart anymore. The output this time is

```
https://www.myDomain.de/checkout/cart/add/uenc/[long alphanumeric string]/product/178/form_key/[alphanumeric string]/
```

so the only difference is the missing '**,**'. Whenever I submit on the button, the page just reloads and nothing is added (but also no error message appears).

I have tried different products and different blocks/cms sites. It seems to be a problem with the template coming from a cms block. This even happens if I create a CMS page and then reference a cms block which references the phtml file - even though the original command is always the same.

Edit: I did a side by side check to see how the output varies when using both methods.

Firstly via CMS page:

```
"https://www.domain/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmVyaW9vLmRlL3Rlc3Qtc2VpdGU,/product/53/form_key/YG7ZM1B76W0SPJRQ/"
```

And now via CMS block:

```
"https://www.domain/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmVyaW9vLmRlL3Byb2R1a3RlL3BvcnJpZGdl/product/53/form_key/YG7ZM1B76W0SPJRQ/"
```

There is a small difference how the URL is created even though the construction is identical.

Is there a special permission needed for cms blocks? Is the comma the culprit for this strange behaviour?

Using Magento CE 1.9.3.7

Comment: Have you tried `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)` instead of using _$this_?

Comment: Yes, also tried that before. Does not change the output or anything else.